# .Net Core open external terminal

Tags: c#, terminal, .net-core

I'm migrating batch script to .Net core and I'm trying to open another terminal from current terminal and run a command (I don't need stderr o stout).

With batch only needs this command: `start cmd /K gulp`. I'm trying to do the same with .Net core but only found the way to run the command inside current terminal.

```
private static string Run (){
    var result = "";
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = $"/c \"gulp browserSync\"";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            result = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying changing this properties in order to open in another terminal:

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

But make an exception:

> UseShellExecute must always be set to false.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you trying to open a new terminal and it wont correct?

Comment: I'm on a terminal, and I'm trying to open a new terminal and run a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @bender-bending answer I found a way to solve it. Due security limitations need user/password credentials in order to autorice current terminal to open a new one.

WorkingDirectory, user, password and domain are required.
Create no window, redirect output and redirect error must be false, in order to see command result in new window.

```
public static void Sample(){
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
            password.Append(key.KeyChar);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            WorkingDirectory = "C:/path_to/Gulp",
            Arguments = $"/c \"gulp browserSync\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            UserName = Machine.User(),
            PasswordInClearText = password.ToString(),
            Domain = Machine.Domain(),
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
        //proc.WaitForExit();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

.Net Core doesn't have a method to obtain user and domain. We can use this class to get this values from environment variables.

```
public static class Machine 
{
    public static string User(){
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");
    }

    public static string Domain(){
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution only works on windows... I tested it on macOS and say: operation is not supported on this platform. If you need a solution that works on both platforms: 
 https://dev.to/equiman/run-a-command-in-external-terminal-with-net-core-d4l

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> UseShellExecute must be false if the UserName property is not null or an empty string, or an InvalidOperationException will be thrown when the Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method is called.

```
startInfo.UserName = null;
```

edit: I'm not sure why you have to pass in the arguments, but if all you want is a new CMD window try this:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:/users/replace/where_gulp_is_located",
        Arguments = @"/c gulp", // add /K if its required, I don't know if its for gulp for to open a new cmd window
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    };

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.Start();

    if (showOut)
    { ///code }

}catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

You wont need `startInfo.UserName` in this case because you are specifying a working directory.