# Open .dll in new console window on Linux .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am able to run `program.dll` in same console window by running:

```
    var process = new Process
    {

        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = "program.dll",
            UseShellExecute = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        }
    };

    process.Start();
```

flag `CreateNoWindow = false` do not open new console as on Windows system.

How to open `program.dll` in new console window on Linux using .NET Core?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382418/net-core-open-external-terminal) but it do not work on linux.

Alternative is [this](https://medium.com/@equiman/run-a-command-in-external-terminal-with-net-core-cc24e3cc9839) but it involves running `program.dll` via .sh scripts which I do not want to do.

Comment: Have you tried adding `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal`?

Comment: @Archer Just tried that and no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to open new console window by using that class. Flag `CreateNoWindow` is ignored on linux in .NETCore 2.0 ([issue on .NETCore github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26337))

However there is workaround available - using xterm to run new console with .dll process.

```
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "xterm",
                Arguments = $"-e dotnet <pathToDll>",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            },
        };
        process.Start();
```